# SSH-Tunnel Port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I have 2 VM, one with private IP-address(behind the NAT) and other with public.
I made SSH-tunnel with NAT. The goal is to connect public VM into network behind NAT and forward some traffic through it.
The point is to spoof an application that runs on this network with a similar one on a public server(in test purposes).

So I made something like that:

Enable tunnel

```
sudo ssh root@31.10.2.165 -w 0:0
```

Addressing

```
ifconfig tun0 10.253.253.1/30 pointopoint 10.253.253.2 - Local

ifconfig tun0 10.253.253.2/30 pointopoint 10.253.253.1 - Remote
```

Adding route to internal network

```
ip route add 10.0.3.0/24 via 10.253.253.1
```

For two-way communication(actually not sure about this one)

```
sudo arp -sD 10.253.253.1 ens18 pub
```

Port Forward on Local

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -s 10.253.253.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I FORWARD 1 -d 10.253.253.1 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.253.253.1 -j MASQUERADE
```

And actually this is almost working, when I switch off application service on Local host it forwards traffic on remote one. But there is a main issue - this local server are sending requests on port 4660 and other (internal applications) respond on port 4661. It looks like I need additional rule to forward all incoming traffic on port 4661 into tunnel interface to port 4660. How to handle this? I'm not very familiar with iptables, but i tried something like that but it doesn't work:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p udp --dport 4661 -j DNAT --to 10.253.253.1:4660
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 10.253.253.1 --dport 4660 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i made it work:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p udp --dport 4661 -j DNAT --to 10.253.253.2:4661(remote tun address)
```